# In IE6, after using AlphaImageLoader filter, links are not clickable anymore

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I am using AlphaImageLoader to display my transparent PNG in IE6. The HTML is,

```
<div id="infoBox">
<a href="links.html">Links</a>
</div>
```

The CSS is,

```
    #infoBox
    {
```

background:url('/images/bg.png') !important;
         background:;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (src='/images/bg.png',sizingMethod='scale');
position:Absolute;

```
    }

    #infoBox a:link
    {
     text-decoration:none;
     position:relative;
    }
```

It is working fine but links are no more clickable in IE6. What I read over internet is that I have to make the element using AlphaImageLoader not using any Position but it is my requirement to use the absolute position. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the absolute positioning on a parent wrapper instead of the element with the background, which can change the circumstances under which the IE6 uninteractivity bug appears.

Amusingly, even changing the size of the background image can affect the bug. See [this](http://www.daltonlp.com/view/217) exasperating discussion.

Comment: It works !!!!  The only issue, now, I am having is that z-index is not working for the wrapper div(position:Absolute). A part of the wrapper div is overlapping another div above and it should have higher z-Index.

Comment: Ensure that all positioned elements on the page (absolute, relative or fixed) have a z-index. When a positioned element is missing a z-index, IE will give it a default index, creating a new stacking context that other browsers don't.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the link's `z-index` to a high value -- that has worked for me to overcome similar bugs.

Comment: hrm. did you try that in conjunction with absolute positioning? just curious.

Comment: I put it here:

#infoBox a:link
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        position:relative;
        z-Index:5002;
    }

Comment: didn't you say you needed to use absolute positioning, as per the necessity of the DXImageTransform filter?

Comment: Yes. #infoBox does have Absolute Positioning and what I have read somewhere on internet, Positioning+AlphaImageLoader will create that effect i.e. links wont be clickable